# com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Permission denied

Tags: java, android

```
[2013-06-12 01:26:56 - SecureFileTransfer] ------------------------------
[2013-06-12 01:26:56 - SecureFileTransfer] Android Launch!
[2013-06-12 01:26:56 - SecureFileTransfer] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-12 01:26:56 - SecureFileTransfer] Performing com.example.sft.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-06-12 01:26:56 - SecureFileTransfer] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect     device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-06-12 01:26:58 - SecureFileTransfer] Uploading SecureFileTransfer.apk onto device '0123456789ABCDEF'
[2013-06-12 01:26:58 - SecureFileTransfer] Failed to install SecureFileTransfer.apk on     device '0123456789ABCDEF': Permission denied
[2013-06-12 01:26:58 - SecureFileTransfer] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Permission denied
[2013-06-12 01:26:58 - SecureFileTransfer] Launch canceled!
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am using eclipse provided by android adt and windows 7. Couple of days before it perfectly installs the app but now don't know what happen it showing this, android phone is on debugging mode, everything is set fine.

Solutions? I have checked similar questions here but nothing solves my problem.

Comment: possible that You changed some things in Your manifest.xml? Even, this could happen, if Your App is already installed. If this is installed, uninstall it and then try again

Comment: @Opiatefuchs this happens with every app i compile, whether its install or not

Comment: Is a custom rom installed in your device?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs No its the default one, the one which manufacturer installed.

Comment: this is very strange. Usually there are some reasons for this behaviour, like custom roms or wrong settings in permissions. One more thing: Have You allowed unknown sources inside Your device? Have You tried to restart Your device?